# rpmbuild -bs fails for Illegal character

Tags: linux, rpm, specifications, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

I am trying to build RPM files for the first time ever.  I have read through the procedures from [RPM Packaging Guide](https://rpm-packaging-guide.github.io/#introduction)

The spec file giving me issues can be found here-
[AWX-RPM-V2](https://github.com/MrMEEE/awx-rpm-v2/blob/main/awx-rpm/awx-rpm.spec)

1. I setup my build tree `rpmdev-setuptree`
2. I copied my spec files into the SPECS folder
3. When running `rpmbuild -bs ~/rpmbuild/SPECS/awx-rpm.spec`  I get the error message - `error: Line 14: Illegal char '?' (hex_code) in: Version:  ¤Version¤`

Can anyone help point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that the person who made that file thought using the unicode character **¤** for [unspecified currency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currency_sign_(typography)) as a quote character was a great idea.

Comment: It looks like they intended to have it be replaced kind of like autotools `@VERSION@` etc. But then didn't. Maybe the file should be called `whatever.spec.in` in the repo as well to not have people directly run `rpmbuild` on it.

Comment: Yep I was right a quick `git grep` shows there's a script that should've been run `scripts/generate-awx-source` will run `sed` repeatedly on that file.

Comment: Thank you for the comments and input.  I should have mentioned that I am not a developer, all my background is system administration.  Having tips and pointers is helpful so I can go research further.